# Is it possible that windows form application create app package?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, win-universal-app, package, windows-10-iot-core

I use rassberry pi 2 with Windows 10 Iot Core.Remote machine of Visual Studio didn't work when I run the my universal windows project with İot Extention(it s say that deploy failed) so I send app package of my project from device portal and it run but I have windows form application and it dont create app package for sending to device portal.

What can I do ? Is it possible that windows form application create app package? or what is any other possible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Forms applications are the old or classic applications. Windows 10 iot is compatible with UWP(Universal Windows Applications) apps only.

You can't create an appx for Windows Forms applications, because this kind of package is for UWP apps.

Update: Now you can use Desktop conversion for UWP( Project Centennial) 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop

Comment: please mark this answer if it's useful for you! thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply ı found a new way so ı didnt look at it sorry

Comment: I used the online dashboard to load all of appx certification and then it was work

Comment: I updated my answer! Please mark this answer if it was useful for you!