# Raspberry pi 3 with windows 10 IOT core operating system does supports winforms?

Tags: winforms, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working in **raspberry pi 3** with windows 10 IOT core operating system. By using visual studio 2015 i am developing universal windows apps and i can able to run the UWP in raspberry pi 3 by using remote server in visual studio 2015. but i want to run the winforms application in raspberry pi 3. can anyone help me please??

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629483/%C4%B0s-it-possible-that-windows-form-application-create-app-package) is an answer you can reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinForms is not supported on Windows 10 IOT. You will need to write your applications for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP).

EDIT: From my comment below, you can bring your WinForms or WPF apps to Windows 10 using the Desktop Bridge - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root#start-the-conversion-process

Comment: thanks @jamescroft92. But another one doubt. Is there is any  cross platform applications for running winforms on windows 10 IOT?

Comment: I don't think there is any way of running a WinForms application on Windows 10 IOT. There is a method for porting a classic Windows app to UWP however and you can find that documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root#start-the-conversion-process

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to rewrite your application to an C#/XAML or VB/XAML project. I have to admit, it's a lot of work, and you will spend some time to learn these new type of application.

You can find a lot of good documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro) to help you from scratch that worked for me.